# QGraphicsView and complex polygon in the background

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am working now on QGraphicsView. I want to draw a big (like 45k points) polygon as the background. Previously, I drew it using OpenGL and VBOs. Now I cannot get OpenGL to work with QPainter, neither can I find an efficient way to draw the polygon in Qt. I have overriden QGraphicsView::drawBackground() method, but I have no idea what to do next and how to get OpenGL working there. Calling painter->beginNativePaiting() results in segfault when I try to create the VBO for the first time. Can you give me any hints so I could go any further?

Answer (score 0):

to use OpenGL rendering in a `QGraphicsView` the documentation says the following

```
To render using OpenGL, simply call setViewport(new QGLWidget)
```

to add the `QPolygon` i would try to add it to the scene using

```
QGraphicsPolygonItem *  addPolygon ( const QPolygonF & polygon, const QPen & pen = QPen(), const QBrush & brush = QBrush() )
```

and to set it as background, you could simply set the `z-order` of the created item ... like

```
void    setZValue ( qreal z )
```

cheers Zai

Comment: Thanks, I am now working on this and I will test the efficiency of both solutions - OpenGL vs Qt.